# menu created dynamically is not working

Tags: wordpress

I am creating a wordpress menu as follows:

```
   <?php wp_nav_menu(
        array(
          'theme_location' =>'main_nav',
          'walker' => new Walker_Nav_Primary()
        )
        ); ?>
```

It generates the menu with exact structured way as I expect. i.e:

```
<ul id="menu-primary" class="menu">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#">Mega</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/">sub 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/">sub2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
  </ul>
```

But hover effect is stop working. When I replace wp_nav_menu() with the generated html it works again. I checked all the jquery code is set at footer.php and my menu is located at header.php and get_header() is called before get_footer(). So everything should be okay if static html is okay. Strange! which wrong is going on behind the scene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, your menu has some issues with closing HTML tag. Better way to debug HTML issue is:

1. hold the menu HTML into a variable.
2. Print the variable inside htmlentities function.
3. Now you can visually see what's wrong with your printed HTML.

Hope that would help you to solve the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add this into the `array`:

```
'echo' => true,
```

Such as

```
   <?php wp_nav_menu(
        array(
          'theme_location' =>'main_nav',
          'walker'         => new Walker_Nav_Primary(),
          'echo'           => true
        )
        ); ?>
```

The official document is shown [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/),